# Desktop switcher, on one monitor only?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen

I have two screens, one I'd like one to be left alone when I switch desktops.

I have my IDE open on a vertical monitor and then my main monitor I have email, browser etc. all open in their open desktops at full screen.

I'd like to switch between them as I do on a single screen set up, but leave my IDE visible regardless of what desktop I'm looking at.

My System:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- GForce 210 - Nvidia x installed and working
- 8GB RAM
- Intel Core i5 processor.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been able to find a setting to easily do this using Ubuntu's Unity Desktop.  Someone can correct me if it exists.

However, the Cinnamon Desktop does allow this.  Cinnamon Settings->Workspaces->'Only use workspaces on primary monitor'

Comment: Oo, cheers.Off to Google Cinnamon now!!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 + Gnome, I've installed "Tweak Tool" (apt install gnome-tweak-tool), then open Tweaks app: Workspaces -> under "Display Handling" choose "Workspaces span displeys" instead of default "Workspaces on primary display only".

Hope it helps.
[image]